# ScriptManager using AJAX gets data from WebService asynchronously and throws an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I’ve got a website in ASP.NET, I’m using ScriptManager to get data from the WebService via AJAX.

When the default.aspx page loads, the onload event is fired and calls the getCategoryDataSet() function from my Javascript.
The getCategoryDataSet() function in the javascript simply calls the methods in the webservice to retrieve the data.

Issue:

When getCategoryDataSet() is called this is the error message I get:

“JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference”
[image]

When the getCategoryDataSet() function is fired it seems that the functions ends before the data from the web service is received. I’m saying this because I’ve added an alert() function before accessing the data of the webservice and it seems that the time I took to press ok on the alert box was enough to retrieve the data from the webservice call.

How can I solve this issue without the use of an alert button to give more time to the call? or is it an other issue?

**Following Photos show the code working with the alert box:**
[image]
[image]

This is my solution explorer:
[image]

**my code for default.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="category_selection_02._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/JScript_01_GetCategories.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="getCategoryDataSet()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebService_GetCategories.asmx" />
        </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div id="divListBoxes">
        THIS DIV WILL BE POPULATED WITH LISTBOXES
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**my code for WebService_GetCategories.asmx.cs:**

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService_GetCategories : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public List<Category> GetCategoriesWebService(int index_left)
    {
        //Debug.WriteLine("in WEBMETHOD");
        List<Category> listCategory = new List<Category>();
        DataSet ds = (new DataBase_DataSet_Generator(index_left)).getDataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();


        dt = ds.Tables[0];

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            Category categoryFields = new Category();
            categoryFields.category_id = (int)dr["category_id"];
            categoryFields.index_left = (int)dr["index_left"];
            categoryFields.index_right = (int)dr["index_right"];
            categoryFields.categoryName = (dr["categoryName"]).ToString();
            //categoryFields.categoryInfo= (dr["categoryInfo"]).ToString();

            listCategory.Add(categoryFields);

            //Debug.WriteLine("This is the total items in the listCategory: "+ listCategory.Count);
        }


        return listCategory;
    }
}
```

**my code for JScript_01_GetCategories.js:**

```
var public_categoryDataSet; //this is the category dataset retreived from the webservice


function getCategoryDataSet() {
    var index_left = 1;

    category_selection_02.WebService_GetCategories.GetCategoriesWebService(index_left, GetCategoryIdSuccessCallBack, GetCategoryIdFailedCallBack)

    function GetCategoryIdSuccessCallBack(results_from_webservice) {
        public_categoryDataSet = results_from_webservice;
    }

    function GetCategoryIdFailedCallBack(errors) {
        alert("AJAX Failed callback invalid data inserted in textbox");
    }
    alert("Alert Fired");  //<--if this alert() call is removed I get an error???
    alert(public_categoryDataSet[0].category_id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is your function `getCategoryDataSet()` is getting executed, and it is stepping through the code *procedurally*. In other words:

1. set `var index_left` = 1
2. Invoke the AJAX call, binding the two callbacks as return parameters
3. (Fire alert)
4. `alert` category_id

So essentially, as soon as step 2 is reached it invokes the call to the web service **then moves on with execution**, thus it reaches step 4 and executes **before** the web service has returned the data, returning a null-reference exception. Putting your dummy alert in the middle (step 3) gives it just enough time to finish loading the web service data before you access it.

### Solution

Any code you write that access a result variable(s) from an AJAX call **must be placed in the success handler**. This is for two reasons:

1. Firstly, you need to make sure the AJAX call has **completed** before you access the resulting variables; thus placing it in the success handler ensures this.
2. Secondly, what happens if your web service method fails, and doesn't return any variables? What happens when you access them? Big issues!

So that's where the **Success** and **Error** callbacks come in - they should contain code that should be executed under each scenario, respectively.

Some code:

```
function getCategoryDataSet() {
    var index_left = 1;

    category_selection_02.WebService_GetCategories.GetCategoriesWebService(
        index_left, 
        GetCategoryIdSuccessCallBack, 
        GetCategoryIdFailedCallBack);

    function GetCategoryIdSuccessCallBack(results_from_webservice) {
        public_categoryDataSet = results_from_webservice;
        //process public_categoryDataSet here
        alert(public_categoryDataSet[0].category_id);
    }

    function GetCategoryIdFailedCallBack(errors) {
        alert("AJAX Failed callback invalid data inserted in textbox");
    }

    alert("Alert Fired");  
    //don't process anything here as it will execute before the AJAX call completes
}
```

Comment: so the fact that the data from results_from_webservice are "processed" in public_categoryDataSet or are processed in general will prevent my code to go to the next step?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly - the `public_categoryDataSet` variable is initialized inside the `GetCategoryIdSuccessCallback` function, but was being accessed before the callback had executed, thus the variable was null.

Comment: is there a way to check if the callback has been completed?

Comment: Not really - you would just want to put any code to be executed after the call has been completed inside the callback, so you can ensure that the ajax call HAS completed. If all your followon code is in the callback, there should be no need to check, as it will just run.